# Is sleeping with your head pointed north dangerous?

Tags: medical-science, biology, magnetism

According to the top-voted answer of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2804/why-not-sleep-with-your-head-facing-north-direction) question:

> When we sleep in this position, iron from the whole body starts to congregate in our brain which can cause headache, Alzheimer’s Disease, Cognitive Decline, Parkinson disease and brain degeneration.

Wow, it seems a bit surreal, especially when [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/does-sleeping-with-our-heads-pointing-towards-north-pose-any-health-risks) other question say that it doesn't have any risk.

Did research after 2011 arose new problem? Or is it that Hindu guy horribly wrong?

Comment: While the post on Hinduism isn't really enough to satisfy our notability requirements, there seem to be many other versions of this claim floating around the internet. I didn't find any that include Alzheimer's and the other mentioned diseases, but most include at least the magnetic field explanation for the rule.

Comment: For a start, that answer implies that the human body is essentially a sack of water with no barrier where metal ions are free to flow, which is plain false. Otherwise The paper cited in the other answer is still a valid answer to this question. The right thing to do would be to ask the answerer on the Hinduism site to cite the "science" that says that. Just adding "science says" in front of something doesn't make it true.

Comment: Iron isn't naturally attracted to North -- only magnetized iron is.

Comment: @nico Scientific issues are usually off-topic on the religion sites. That avoids the whole issue pretty effectively. They don't have the experts to judge a scientific answer, but they can judge the religious reasons and doctrines behind it.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: While I understand why you do want to close this as duplicate, I d like to make you reread the question and notice I where wondering if any research changed the answer since thoses 3 years

Comment: @DrakaSAN We don't open new questions on the off chance that there's been "new research". If you want to get new answers to the old question, you should put a Bounty on it. (Personally I would suggest not worrying about this, though, it's clearly a myth.)

Comment: @Fabian: true but the (now deleted? can't see it anymore) answer on the Hinduism website stated that "science says...". So there is an appeal to science without citing any science. I wouldn't challenge a religion reason, but if science is called upon I would definitely ask for references, especially when knowing that science says otherwise, even on a religious website.

Comment: @nico, It's not deleted. The claim is in the penultimate paragraph of Mr. Alien's answer on hinduism.SE

Comment: @BrianS: that is not the quote reported in the question

Comment: @nico, Apologies, you're right.

Comment: @Fabian: The post does as been deleted, after I asked him to post where he found thoses information in the first place here. May be a sign that this question is a duplicate and no new claim has been made. Thanks everyone : )

Comment: If the iron in your body was attracted enough to the magnetic north pole to actually move inside you, then a simple MRI scan would rip you apart, without fail.